# Main Thread is not waiting for the Worker Thread to finish in Completable Future

Tags: multithreading, java-8, parallel-processing

//Main Thread is not waiting for the Worker Thread to finish in Completable Future. When I run System.out.println on Completables they are not running in the order.

```
public class CompletableFutureMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Main Task : Thread Name=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    CompletableFuture<String> stringCompletableFuture = null;
    CompletableFuture<Integer> intCompletableFuture = null;

    stringCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Task 1 : Thread Name=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return getMeWelcomeMessage();
    });

    intCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Task 2 : Thread Name=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return getMeARandomInteger();
    });

        System.out.println(stringCompletableFuture.get());
        System.out.println(intCompletableFuture.get().toString());


}

private static String getMeWelcomeMessage() {
    return "Trying Completable Future";
}

private static Integer getMeARandomInteger() {
    return new Random().nextInt(100);
}

private static Double getMeARandomDouble() {
    return new Random().nextDouble();
}


}
```

Comment: Why should they run in order? You have started two *asynchronous* operations. This implies the absence of an ordering relation. And what has waiting to do with it? Does a train change its schedule when you are waiting for it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not waiting for all the Completables to join.
Run your System.out.println() after joining the completableFutures.

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(stringCompletableFuture, intCompletableFuture).join();
```

Also completable.get() can result in java.lang.InteruptedException and java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException. You need to handle these Checked Exceptions.
Sample Code Snippet

```
public class CompletableFutureMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Main Task : Thread Name=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    CompletableFuture<String> stringCompletableFuture = null;
    CompletableFuture<Integer> intCompletableFuture = null;

    stringCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Task 1 : Thread Name=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return getMeWelcomeMessage();
    });

    intCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Task 2 : Thread Name=" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return getMeARandomInteger();
    });
    

    
CompletableFuture.allOf(stringCompletableFuture, intCompletableFuture).join();

    try {
        System.out.println(stringCompletableFuture.get());
        System.out.println(intCompletableFuture.get().toString());
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
    }

}

private static String getMeWelcomeMessage() {
    return "Trying Completable Future";
}

private static Integer getMeARandomInteger() {
    return new Random().nextInt(100);
}

private static Double getMeARandomDouble() {
    return new Random().nextDouble();
}


}
```

Comment: Since `get()` does wait for the result, there is no need to do `allOf(…).join()`. This redundant waiting has no influence on the result.